# Lambda: Filter Lists :: List::get[0] non static error: Alternative

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

`Map<String, List<List<String>>>` using java8 Lamda `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(List::get[0]));`

where `List::get[0]` cannot be applied as `Non Static Method cannot be reference from the static content`

Any easy alternative to achieve same.

Here is My code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LamdaTest
{

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> lists = populateList();
        Map<String, List<List<String>>> listMap = lists.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(List::get(0)));
          System.out.println(listMap);

}

public static List<List<String>> populateList (){

    List<String>  list =Arrays.asList("10","test10");
    List<String>  list2 =Arrays.asList("10","test10");
    List<String>  list3 =Arrays.asList("11","test11");
    List<String>  list4 =Arrays.asList("11","test11");
    List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(list,list2,list3,list4);

    return lists;
}
}
```

Expected Output

```
{10=[[10, test10], [10, test10]], 11=[[11, test11], [11, test11]]}
```

Comment: How does your desired output look like?

Comment: what is this for ? List::get[0]  you cant use if it s not static method ?

Comment: @Flown: I am expecting `Map <String, List<String>>` where filerred grouped output is saved in map

Comment: @Bolzano: `List::get[0]` could act as collect group, Since get[0]  non static I cannot use i

Comment: @Ashish I know what type you're expecting. My question was: how does the result - I mean the content of the Map - look like in your example.

Comment: @Flown: Added Expected output of Map

Comment: Your expected output looks like a `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`, so you should not `flatMap` the stream content and just do `groupingBy(l -> l.get(0))` in this case.

Comment: @AlexisC.: Thanks for pointing out, Updated Questions, problem is `get(0)` is non static which gives error

Comment: @Ashish Well you can't use a method reference in this case, so you'll have to resort to a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a method reference in this case, so you need to use a lambda expression.

```
Map<String, List<List<String>>> listMap = populateList().stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0)));
```